# MySQL | update cell based on a function

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, substring

I have database where the names of the users is like this "Ortega, Rafael" but i need it with the first name in the first position and without the comma.

i found this function that let me substring by a delimemeter:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

but here i got stucked when i tried to write the UPDATE query

```
UPDATE `names_table` set `name` = CONCAT(
    SPLIT_STR(
        SELECT `name` FROM `names_table` WHERE <I need help here>,
        ',',
        1
    ), 
    " ",
    SPLIT_STR(
        SELECT `name` FROM `names_table` WHERE <I need help here>,
        ',',
        2
    ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `substring_index()`:

```
update names_table
    set name = concat_ws(' ',
                         trim(substring_index(name, ',', -1)), 
                         trim(substring_index(name, ',', 1))
                        )
    where name like '%,%';
```

I'm not sure why you would want to invent another function to do this.

Comment: WOW, my bad... i didnt have knowledge of the substring_index function so i googled for it and someone said that you needed to create the function by yourself. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!